# Change Language with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string, multilingual

I am building a multilingual site, which will be in English, German and French. The English Site will be the **root**, other will be in their **subdirectories**:

- **English**: example.com
- **German**: example.com/**de**
- **French**: example.com/**fr**

I am having difficulties to find **clean solution** to redirect from language to language using Query String. (**?lang=en**, **?lang=de**, ?**lang=fr**)

This code is working, but I think it its to long:

```
# Languages
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

# Deutsch (Change FR to DE, or add DE if English)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=de
RewriteRule ^fr/(.*) de/$1? [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=de
RewriteRule ^(.*) de/$1? [L,R=301]

# English (Remove DE if German, Remove FR if French)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=en
RewriteRule ^de/(.*) /$1? [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=en
RewriteRule ^fr/(.*) /$1? [L,R=301]

# French (Change DE to FR, or add FR if English)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=fr
RewriteRule ^de/(.*) fr/$1? [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=sq
RewriteRule ^(.*) fr/$1? [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Is there any **better sollution**, so **in case we add more languages**, there will be **shorter, cleaner code**.

Its first time I am working on htaccess at all!

Thanks!

Comment: It might be worth trying to do in php instead? and just check the lang GET and change the header accordingly.

Comment: Its a WordPress multisite and each site has its language, so it will be hard to change each header.I was thinking with htaccess its gonna be the easier, although I had no idea how to change language (if no plugin for that is wanted)

Answer (score 0):

**Why don't you link to the desired language by dir and without a query string?**
So if your user want's to change the language you could provide a link from lets say `example.org/de/some-page` to `example.org/fr/some-page` instead of using `example.org/de/some-page?lang=fr` and then redirect him anyway to `example.org/fr/some-page` .. This doesn't make sense to me.

And if you want the user to view a page in a specific language, you could redirect him by php or some other serverside language.

You would just need a .htaccess like this to prevent the user from viewing any site without a selected language:

```
RewriteEngine on

# add EN if there was no language selected
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^fr|de|en
RewriteRule ^(.*) en/$1? [L,R=301]
```